# How to sort an array of records into descending order

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, record

I have a csv file called sample.csv that I have converted into a record, this record is set up with an string value and a integer value like so:

```
[Name,10]
[Name1,12]
[Name2,14]
```

I would like to be able to sort these records into descending order and then eventually print the names and scores of the three highest scoring pupils and also the name and score of the lowest scoring pupil.Here is my code so far, I am unable to sort the records by integer value.

```
import csv
file = open("sample.csv")
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
file.close()

sortedFile=[]

sortedFile=sorted(rows, key=lambda rows: rows[1])

print(sortedFile)
```

Edit:

A really helpful person commented but now for whatever they have deleeted their comment.

```
import csv
file = open("sample.csv")
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
file.close()

sortedFile=[]

sortedFile=sorted(rows, key=lambda rows: int(rows[1]))[::-1]

print(sortedFile[0])
print(sortedFile[1])
print(sortedFile[2])
print(sortedFile[-1])
```

My code now looks like this and I am nearly finished, I believe I am missing something really simple, all I would like is the some text near the array saying

```
"The person with the highest score is", (name[0]),"with a score of,(score[0])
"The person with the highest score is", (name[1]),"with a score of,(score[1])
"The person with the highest score is", (name[2]),"with a score of,(score[2])
"The person with the lowest score is", (name[-1]),"with a score of,(score[-1])
```

Comment: `sortedFile=sorted(rows, key=lambda rows: int(rows[1]))`?

Answer (score 0):

You sort in your code in ascending order, and from the condition it is necessary in descending order.

Try this option:

Code:

```
rows=[['A',10],
['B',12],
['C',11]]

sortedFile=sorted(rows, key=lambda rows: int(rows[1]))[::-1]

if len(sortedFile) > 1:    
    print(sortedFile)
    for i in range(len(sortedFile) - 1):
        print(sortedFile[i])
    print(sortedFile[-1])
elif len(sortedFile) == 1:
    print(sortedFile)
    print(sortedFile[0])
else:
    print('list is empty')
```

This code takes into account 3 conditions. If the list length is greater than 1, it is equal to 1 and is equal to 0.

---

For a beautiful output, you can use f-strings, that is, for example, like this:

```
print(f'The person with the highest score is {name[0]}, with a score of {score[0]}')
```

I'll show you by my own example:

```
if len(sortedFile) > 1:
    for i in range(len(sortedFile) - 1):
        print(f'The person with the highest score is {sortedFile[i][0]}, with a score of {sortedFile[i][1]}')
    print(f'The person with the highest score is {sortedFile[-1][0]}, with a score of {sortedFile[-1][1]}')
elif len(sortedFile) == 1:
    print(f'The person with the highest score is {sortedFile[0][0]}, with a score of {sortedFile[0][1]}')
else:
    print('list is empty')
```

Comment: This is perfect mate ty, I tried to reply earlier but I think that something maybe broke, I was wondering If there was a way to have some text as well so I could say (name0) with a score of (score[0]), (name[1]) with a score of (score[1) etc?

Comment: You can use the `reverse=True` optional keyword argument to `sorted`, rather than reversing the list with `[::-1]`

Comment: @mhannah04 It is possible, I have completed the answer.

Comment: @Stef You're right, I just decided this way)

Comment: @Tehnorobot this is great, tyvm!

Comment: @Tehnorobot I am unfortunately getting an error I believe I must define both parts of my record or something else as name and score are undefined

Comment: @mhannah04 If you still need help, I have added code that implements your requirements. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
 sortedFile = sorted(rows, key=lambda rows: int(rows[1]))?
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a list, you can call `sort` with `key` argument to specify how to sort the list. In this case, you can use negative value `-x[1]` to sort it in reverse order.

```py
data = [['Name',10],
['Name1',12],
['Name2',14]]

data.sort(key = lambda x: -x[1])
```

Result:

```py
[['Name2', 14], ['Name1', 12], ['Name', 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following changes:

- [Using `with` to open the file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files);
- [Using the `reverse=True` optional keyword argument to `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html);
- Using [formatted strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) and [builtin function `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate and print the first, second, third and last scores.

```py
import csv

with open("sample.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    sortedFile = sorted(csvreader, key=lambda rows: int(rows[1]), reverse=True)

print(sortedFile)

for (i,place) in zip([0,1,2,-1], ['highest', '2nd highest', '3rd highest', 'lowest']):
    print('The person with the {} score is {} with a score of {}.'.format(place, sortedFile[i][0], sortedFile[i][1]))
```

Example input `sample.csv`

```
Alice,12
Max,11
Medhi,18
Chen,17
Sasha,15
```

Example output

```
[['Medhi', '18'], ['Chen', '17'], ['Sasha', '15'], ['Alice', '12'], ['Max', '11']]
The person with the highest score is Medhi with a score of 18.
The person with the 2nd highest score is Chen with a score of 17.
The person with the 3rd highest score is Sasha with a score of 15.
The person with the lowest score is Max with a score of 11.
```